# python selenium element not visible

Tags: python, selenium

```
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.suntrust.com/')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-on-3A69E29D-79E0-403E-
                                     9352-5261239ADD89-user"]')
elem.send_keys('your-username')
```

I'm having two problems:

1) The window doesn't open up in full screen, meaning the username field isn't physically visible. How do I open the url in a new tab instead of a new window.

2) Other posts suggest that the element is faked by JavaScript so that webdriver can't see it.

I've tried `find_element_by` in all the other locators.

Comment: Try `browser.maximize_window()` to open browser window in full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The `xpath` you have constructed is not unique. The `xpath` matches exactly to 2 elements on the HTML DOM. So Selenium was trying to `send_keys` on the first matching element which was invisible. Hence the error `element not visible`. The `xpath` used in the following code block identifies the `User ID` field uniquely and sends the text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.suntrust.com/')
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//section[@role="main"]//input[@id="sign-on-3A69E29D-79E0-403E-9352-5261239ADD89-user"]')
elem.send_keys('your-username')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I'll try to figure out the "why" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be answered by a simple line of code that you need to include

```
browser.maximize_window()
```

would maximise your window. Another option is to set a specific window size like

```
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
```

You can use both to achieve the browser being open to a maximum size.

Another point that I would make is that, if you're a beginner, try using more of `CSS Selectors` instead of the `Xpath`. They are much faster than Xpath's. Please see a detailed [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator) on SQA about what makes a good locator.

For your case, the CSS Selector for the sign in field would be

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#sign-on-3A69E29D-79E0-403E-9352-5261239ADD89-user')
```

For password, it would be

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#sign-on-3A69E29D-79E0-403E-9352-5261239ADD89-password')
```

For Sign On button it would be

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.suntrust-login-button')
```

Please read more about CSS Selectors and try using them more often in your code.

Comment: Is there a difference between using "driver" and "browser".  When I use "driver" it it underlined in red, giving me an error.

Comment: You can use `browser` instead of driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute xpath then you can send the text in textbox.

Below code will do that

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window() # to open full size window
browser.get('https://www.suntrust.com/')

# browser.implicitly_wait(10)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sign-on-3A69E29D-79E0-403E-9352-5261239ADD89-user"]')))

elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='suntrust-login-form-herosignon']/div[2]/form/div[1]/input[1]")
elem.send_keys('your-username')
elem1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='suntrust-login-form-herosignon']/div[2]/form/div[2]/input[1]")
elem1.send_keys('your-password')
```